# dd fails in postgres backup from one server to another

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, dd, postgresql

I've got a server which is running out of space. Unfortunately it doesn't even have enough space anymore to backup a postgres database I've got running on it. So I now want to backup the running postgres DB to another server for which I've found the following command on [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/backup-postgres-mysql-securely-using-ssh.html):

```
pg_dump -U USERNAME YOUR-DATABASE-NAME | ssh user@remote.server.com "dd of=/pgsql/$(date +'%d-%m-%y')"
```

Unfortunately I get an error saying:

> Password: dd: failed to open ‘/pgsql/23-02-15’: No such file or directory

Since I'm still learning I'm unsure what the `"dd of=/pgsql/$(date +'%d-%m-%y')"` part of the command actually is for. Could anybody enlighten me a litte bit in what it tries to do, what goes wrong and how I can solve this? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have the /pgsql dir on your target machine or change "of=" to an existing path.
"dd of=some_file" is equivalent to "cat >some_file".